# adobe acrobat actions or batch processing - js get paths of all files in a folder

Tags: batch-processing, acrobat, acrobat-sdk

So I would like to create an action that will take a folder, and display/store its contents filenames (as I would later want to manipulate the files on this folder via their filenames).  I believe this is achieved via javascript.

I did the ff:
create new action 
-> starts with -> A Folder on my Computer

I have no idea what to do next.

Any help would be awesome.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

A document's path can be accessed via `this.path`, the file name can be accessed via `this.documentFileName`. If all you want is a list of paths, you could print them to the console via `console.println(this.path);`.

There are likely better methods to achieve your objective than via Acrobat's batch processes, but without more detail, it's hard to point you in a direction.